# Retrieve data in view sent from controller

Tags: c#, linq, asp.net-mvc-4

```
 /// <summary>  Model to fetch data
        /// Get All Countries 
        /// </summary>
        /// <returns></returns>
        public IQueryable GetAllCountry()
        {
            using (Context context = new Context())
            {
                var countries = context.COUNTRY.Select(c => new
                {
                    country = new
                    {
                        ID = c.ID,
                        Description = c.DESCRIPTION,
                        CountryPhoneCode = c.COUNTRY_PHONE_CODE,
                        Currency = c.CURRENCY.CURRENCY,
                        Language = context.LANGUAGE.Where(l => l.COUNTRY_ID == c.ID).Select( l => new { lang = l.DESCRIPTION }).Distinct()
                    }
                });

                return countries;
            }

        }
```

// my controller

```
//
        // GET: /Country/

        public ActionResult DisplayCountries()
        {
            DAL library = new DAL();

            var country = library.GetAllCountry();
            ViewBag.countries = country;
            return View("DisplayCountries");
        }

//My View

@{
    ViewBag.Title = "DisplayCountries";
}

<h2>Country list</h2>

   @{
       var countries = ViewBag.countries;

        foreach (var country in countries)
        {
            @country.country.ID; // property country is not defined. error!
        }
   }
```

How do I display the data sent from controller to View. Do I need to create a separate class to display the data? Is there no other way to do this ? What are the alternatives if I dont want to use ViewBag ?

Comment: Why don't you create a model that holds your country entities? I think easiest way is creating a model.

Comment: there are too many similar linq queries to be executed. Can't I do it without creating new classes. I am using EF

Comment: what is coming in countries have you checked it by debugging?

Comment: I am able to get the values to the view.I just don't know how to display it.

Comment: My error is :
Server Error in '/' Application.

'object' does not contain a definition for 'countries'

Description: An unhandled exception occurred during the execution of the current web request. Please review the stack trace for more information about the error and where it originated in the code. 

Exception Details: Microsoft.CSharp.RuntimeBinder.RuntimeBinderException: 'object' does not contain a definition for 'countries'

Source Error: 


Line 12:         foreach (var country in countries)
Line 13:         {
Line 14:             @country.countries.ID; 
Line 15:         }
Line 16:    }

Answer (score 0, accepted):

make a Class like this:

```
public class CountryVm
{
public int ID {get;set;} 
public string Description {get;set;}
public string CountryPhoneCode {get;set;}
public double Currency {get;set;}
public string Language {get;set;}
}
```

and code:

```
public List<CountryVm> GetAllCountry()
{
using (Context context = new Context())
            {
                var countries = (from c in context.COUNTRY
                                select new CountryVm
                        {
                         ID = c.ID,
                         Description = c.DESCRIPTION,
                         CountryPhoneCode = c.COUNTRY_PHONE_CODE,
                         Currency = c.CURRENCY.CURRENCY,
                         Language = context.LANGUAGE
                                    .Where(l => l.COUNTRY_ID == c.ID)
                                    .Select( l => new { lang = l.DESCRIPTION }).Distinct()
                    }).ToList<CountryVm>();
                }

                return countries;
}
```

In view:

```
@{

var list = ViewBag.countries as List<CountryVm>;

foreach(var item in list)
{
 item.ID
 ....

}
```

Comment: The cast is Invalid. Please look again.

Comment: Thanks for the reply. I have a doubt please help me clear it. I am using EF. so EF has already created all the model classes. So Again do I need to create classes like these ?? Is it mandatory. Cant I just pass the value to the view and display it directly ?

Comment: you can use the country class then, where i am passing CountryVM you can pass Country class is it is in your models

Comment: can you tell me the code to access countries in view ?

Answer (score 0):

You should switch to a strongly typed view model -- ie a view model class

Create a view model that should contain those properties

```
public class Country ... etc..

     new Country() {                  ID = c.ID,
                        Description = c.DESCRIPTION,
                        CountryPhoneCode = c.COUNTRY_PHONE_CODE,
                        Currency = c.CURRENCY.CURRENCY,
                        Language = context.LANGUAGE.Where(l => l.COUNTRY_ID == c.ID).Select( l => new { lang = l.DESCRIPTION }).Distinct()
                    }
```

In your controller return the list of this class containing all countries, something like

```
List<Country> country = library.GetAllCountry();
```

In your view add this add the top of the page

```
@model IEnumerable<XNet.Repository.Model.EditRoomTypeViewModel>
```

And in the for loop simply address it by the property ...

:)