# Model is null when sent from controller to view

Tags: asp.net-core, asp.net-core-mvc

I'm getting a `System.NullReferenceException` for `Model` in my view:

```
@page
@model List<MyApp.Models.Student>

<div>
@{
    string sHtml = TestPageView.GetHtml(Model); // <-- NullReferenceException here
}

@Html.Raw(sHtml)
</div>
```

Here's my controller action:

```
public IActionResult TestPage()
{
    return View(SomeStudents.Students);
}
```

Here's my `Student` model:

```
namespace Models
{
    public class Student
    {
        public int Id;
        public string Name;
        public int Age;
        public int Grade;
    }
}
```

And the list comes from here:

```
namespace Data 
{
    public class SomeStudents 
    {
        public static List<Student> Students { get; } = new  List<Student>() {
           new Student() { Id = 1, Name = "Adam", Age = 20, Grade = 69 },
           new Student() { Id = 2, Name = "Mark", Age = 21, Grade = 80 },
           new Student() { Id = 3, Name = "Bill", Age = 18, Grade = 51 }
        };
    }
}
```

I've reviewed several slightly similar Q&As reporting the same problem, including these:

- [Model not passed from controller to view](https://stackoverflow.com/q/57053669)
- [Retrieve data in view sent from controller](https://stackoverflow.com/q/23081603)

...but I'm not finding anything that addresses my exact scenario (which I believe to be quite simple and not at all complex, which is confounding).

I tried explicitly naming the view, as in [this answer](https://stackoverflow.com/a/29628656):

```
public IActionResult TestPage()
{
  return View("TestPage", SomeStudents.Students);
}
```

I also tried adjusting the view a bit, using a slightly modified excerpt from [this example](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/aspnet/core/tutorials/first-mvc-app/adding-model?view=aspnetcore-8.0&tabs=visual-studio#strongly-typed-models-and-the-model-directive):

```
@page
@model List<MyApp.Models.Student>

<div>
  @foreach (var item in Model) { // <-- NullReferenceException here
    @Html.DisplayFor(modelItem => item.Name)
  }
</div>
```

In all cases, however, attempts to access `Model` in the view result in the same `NullReferenceException`.

How do I pass the list of `Student`s to my view?

Comment: And also - the  `Student` model class should have **properties** - not fields - `public int Id { get; set; };`

Comment: Got it, thanks for spotting that. FYI I always do so when in VB.NET, my chosen dialect. It's just a bit easier to miss it in C#, that's all.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

The solution is to remove the `@page` directive.

That directive is for a Razor Page, not an MVC view.